# Dynamically add the values in titanium tableview

Tags: javascript, iphone, arraylist, titanium, tableview

I have listed out the categories on 1st page, subcategories on 2nd page and products on 3rd page. Now I have added the products to the cart. now will go back to categories page again and will add the products to cart. If we need to view the items in the cart, we can declare a global array[] and will add the data's to that array[]. But here if I have added the 3 items means the final item which was added recently that item only showing in the cart list items page. But I want to display the added 3 items. Can you please check my code and find out my issue.

```
Ti.App.data = [];
data=[
            {title:productlist_product,
            price:productlist_product_price,
            quantity:selectedqty},
         ];
var myObjectString = JSON.stringify(data);
```

**EDIT:**
Ti.API.info("DATA-length"+" "+data.length);

Here am getting the value as 1 .But in the cart page having the 3 products. i need to add that 3 products value to data[].Can you please give me solution ?

**EDIT:**

Now i have added the values dynamically in the array[] using below code.

```
 data = [
{title:productlist_product,
price:productlist_product_price,
image:productlist_product_image,
quantity:selectedqty},
];

// append new value to the array
 data.push({title:productlist_product,
            price:productlist_product_price,
            image:productlist_product_image,
            quantity:selectedqty});

     // display all values
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 console.log(data[i]);
   }
   var myObjectString = JSON.stringify(data);

  Ti.API.info("PRICE"+" "+myObjectString);
```

Now i have added the same product with different quantity means that the product is listed separately. But if i have added same product with different quantity means want to list out the product  name in the list single time .but the quantity is need to update on the products.

For Eg:
if i have added the "Android development " product with 2 quantity in the cart. Again i will add the same product with "Android development"  product with 4 quantity means the list is displaying right now :

```
 PRICE [{"title":"Android development","quantity":2},
        {"title":"Android development","quantity":4}]
```

But i want to looking like the below :

```
 PRICE [{"title":"Android development","quantity":6}]
```

Comment: Please explain more the app flow, you have three views, the first one is for categories, and when the user selects a category, the app navigates to the second view that contains subcategories and the same with products, am I right ?

Comment: @Zabady yes exactly you are correct .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i have added the values dynamically in the array[] using the below code.

```
data = [
{title:productlist_product,
price:productlist_product_price,
image:productlist_product_image,
quantity:selectedqty},
];

// append new value to the array
 data.push({title:productlist_product,
            price:productlist_product_price,
            image:productlist_product_image,
            quantity:selectedqty});

     // display all values
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 console.log(data[i]);
   }
   var myObjectString = JSON.stringify(data);

  Ti.API.info("PRICE"+" "+myObjectString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must assign the array of data to the table's data property in order to display these objects as tableView rows. Let's say:

```
Ti.UI.backgroundColor = 'white';
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var tableData = [ {title: 'Apples'}, {title: 'Bananas'}, {title: 'Carrots'}, {title: 'Potatoes'} ];

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
data: tableData});
win.add(table);
win.open();
```

Or, you may also want to add rows using *table.setData*
customTableView.setData(data);

```
var customTableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({ BackgroundColor:'White', style: Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED, });
data.push({title:productlist_product, price: productlist_product_price,quantity: selectedqty});
customTableView.data = data;
```

Comment: Hi Can you please check my edited question and give me a solution.this is exactly i have followed and needed...

Comment: Do you mind sharing a runnable test case to help out troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var productData = [
                    {Product_Name: 'Apples',Product_Price :50,Product_qty :5}, 
                    {Product_Name: 'Banana',Product_Price :40,Product_qty :5},
                    {Product_Name: 'Carrots',Product_Price :90,Product_qty :5}
                ];
var tableData = [];
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var tableRow = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        title :"Name :"+data[i].Product_Name+"      Price : "+data[i].Product_Price,
    });
    tableData.push(tableRow);
}

var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data: tableData
});
win.add(tableView);
```

Comment: i have added 3 products totally...But the last product only displaying in the tableview.i have 3 views.one is for categories,when a user selects a category, the app navigates to the second view that contains subcategories and same with products. first i have added one products then i will go back to categories page then will add another 2 products means the last product only showing in the list which was recently added by user .but i need to show all the added products. can you please help me.

Comment: I think you are not updating your global array properly, Whenever you add or delete an item update your Ti.App.data array.

Comment: how can i update the global array ? if i have clicking the button , the product detail will be add to data[]. again i will go back to category page,if it selected category it will go to subcategory page, if it's selected subcategory it will go to product page.here we will select the product and click the button means the currect product detail was added on the data[]. But i have declared this data[] is globally only...then why all the value is not added on the data[].that last selected product value only added on data[].Can you please explain it through code for update the data[]